# Restarting java game based on selection of JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, program-entry-point

I have a simple game in which I have a JOptionPane popup giving the choice of YES or NO.

So if the user hits NO then the game shuts down ofcourse however if the user hits YES I want the game to restart.

I have got this to work by the following : (Just by calling the main() method again. 
    main.Main.main(null);

The problem :

It's starting another instance of the game however the previous instead is there as well.

How can I close the previous instance before starting a new instance? or what other ways are there to get around this?

Here is the class code with the JOptionPane

```
    public void popupWinMessage(String message)
{
     //default icon, custom title
    int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null,
        message,
        "",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Alright, here we go again");
        main.Main.main(null);
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for playing the battleships game");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Here is my updated main method (I'm still pretty confused on what is going on):

```
package main;

imports

public class Main {

public Controller theController = new Controller(new Game(), new Frame());
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    newGame();
}


public static void newGame()
{
    theController.;
}
```

}

The directory of my whole game looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kze94.png

The method where the JOption pane is located is in the view's Frame class.

```
public Controller(final Game newGame, final Frame newView) 
{
    this.game = newGame;

    this.view = newView;
    this.view.setVisible(true);


    //Gets the board arrays into these local variables here for us to use
    playerBoard = newGame.DisplayPlayerBoard();
    computerBoard = newGame.DisplayCompBoard();


    colourGrids();

    this.view.addGridActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
            Object o = ae.getSource();
            if(o instanceof JButton) 
            {
                JButton btn = (JButton) o;

                int xValue = (Integer) btn.getClientProperty("row");
                int yValue =  (Integer) btn.getClientProperty("column");

                int tempShipType = computerBoard[xValue][yValue];

                newGame.tryHitComputer(xValue, yValue);

                btn.setEnabled(false);


                if(tempShipType != -1)
                {
                   if(newGame.checkShipStatus(tempShipType) == true)
                      {
                         System.out.println(shipDowns[tempShipType]);
                         newView.popupMessage(shipDowns[tempShipType]);
                      }
                }

                //Code here for the computer to try hit your ships

                newGame.tryHitPlayer();



                colourGrids();

                System.out.println(newGame.isGameWon());

                if (newGame.isGameWon() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Game has been won, do something to stop it at some point");
                    newView.popupWinMessage("Game has been won\nDo you wish to play again?");
                }
                if (newGame.isGameLost() == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("Game has been lost, the silly AI has beaten you\nDo you wish to play again?");
                    newView.popupWinMessage("Game has been lost, the silly AI has beaten you\nDo you wish to play again?");
                }

            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("The listener was not attached to a JButton as expected - " + o.getClass());
            }
        }
    });





}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Also be sure to **read** the pop-up of a tag before slapping it on a post.  This has nothing to do with [tag:restart] as used in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call the main method again.  Have a start() method which starts your game and get the dialog to call that when the answer is "yes"

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a `restartGame()` method to your `Controller` class. Since you call `popupWinMessage()` from the `Controller` constructor, you can modify it to take a `Controller` object and pass it the `this` reference. Then `popupWinMessage()` method can simply call the `restartGame()` method on the instance that is passed to it.

Comment: I'm not understand this too well. in my Main package where the main method is, I basically took the code out of the main method that creates a new instance of the game and put it into a public static void method called newGame(). In the main() method I put that newGame() method. In the controller I put a method that calls the main methods newGame(). Then in my view I called the Controllers method when they chose the JOption. It's not working however because in the method in my view I can't do controller.Controller.restartGame(); - Doesn't let me (using eclipse)

Comment: Yep, still leaving the previous instance of the game in the background - http://i.imgur.com/hE4SfeG.png

Comment: I created a reference of the Controller in the main method :  public Controller theController = new Controller(new Game(), new Frame()); ... Now I just don't know what i'm suppose to do in the restartGame() method in the controller itself

Comment: @Jagga Please edit your question to show some simplified code that illustrates what you have done.

Comment: Well Here is how my main method is looking like at the moment : http://i.imgur.com/WPCG58J.png

Comment: @Jagga Also, please show the constructor for your `Controller` class.

Comment: Have you given up on me yet @Code-Guru :p

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28483/discussion-between-code-guru-and-jagga)